# How to Use Zend Library without installation of Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

How to use zend library without using zend framework installation?

I am trying to use zend library(Mail and Mime) without zend framework installation, its not returning any error messages...
       but for my project i'm using Mail and Mime library only, How to use Zend Library without installing zend framework ..

Thanks,
Vinoth S

Comment: Zend Framework is not a monolith. (Nearly?) each of his classes can be used independently. Just follow the instructions below :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download Zend Framework and put it into a folder accessible by your PHP. Then either do

```
include '/path/to/folder/containing/Zend/lib/Zend/Mail.php';
include '/path/to/folder/containing/Zend/lib/Zend/Mime.php';

$mailer = new Zend_Mail;
```

Or - better and more conventient - [setup your autoloader](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=setup+autoloading+php) and/or include path so PHP can find the classes directly, without you having to include them.

Also see

- the [requirements appendix](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/requirements.html) for a detailed list of requirements for Zend Framework.

Comment: yeah.. thanks gordon, am using "set_include_path('lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());"... Its working fine...

Answer (score 7):

Register the autoloader and set include path like this:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath('./library'),//the path
    get_include_path(),
)));
require "Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php";
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

Answer (score 3):

I've done it more than once to integrate zend libs in other non-zend projects.
Autoloader is not suggested for just inclusion of some libraries as it involves in worse performances (see zend reference about |end_Loader for that).
The best way (from both clear code and performances point of view) is very simple:

1) set the include path: (necessary or you'll have fatal inclusion errors):

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    '/',
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

2) do a "require_once" of the library/ies you need, following the structure Zend/
e.g:

```
require_once "Zend/Mail.php"; 
//you can use now Zend_Mail* classes
```

note1: you don't have to place a "require_once" of all the needed classes, the main included class already do a require_once of the dependent classes.