# Send attatchment using php mail()

Tags: php

I want to attach a image as an attachment using mail() function.
I am using xampp and want the image to be sent from my computer to an email id.
This code is sending text email easily:

```
<?php 
    if(mail('abc@gmail.com','Hello','Testing  Testing','From:xyz@gmail.com'))
    {
       echo "Success";
    } else {
       echo "Fail";
    }
?>
```

I want to add an image after it using normal mail method of php.

Comment: simple advise: don't. use alternatives like swiftmailer or phpmailer.

Comment: i want to keep it simple!

Comment: yes, I can read. I was just advising not to do that. with mail(), you'll have a lot of issues to deal with that you don't have to resolve using alternatives.

Comment: that is why you want to use the alternatives - to keep it simple. implementing these by yourself using mail() is *hard* to get right and working reliably in different scenarios.

Comment: hmmm .... how can it be done using phpmailer.I haven't used it till now.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the pear library for composing or sending the mail.

```
 include_once('Mail.php');
 include_once('Mail_Mime/mime.php');
 $message = new Mail_mime();

 $message->setTXTBody($text);

$message->addAttachment($path_of_uploaded_file);

$body = $message->get();

$extraheaders = array("From"=>$from, "Subject"=>$subject,"Reply-To"=>$visitor_email);

$headers = $message->headers($extraheaders);

$mail = Mail::factory("mail");

$mail->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

here is a [way](http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-email-form-attachment.html#pearinstall)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Mail class from the Zend library, very simple and no reliance on PEAR.

Its been covered in a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164766/how-to-use-zend-library-without-installation-of-zend-framework).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Swiftmailer. It is up to date, easy to install and use. You can [install](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/installing.html) it via PEAR, but there are lots of other options you might find more convenient as well.

Example code to send a mail with an attachement taken from the manual:

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

 // Create the message
 $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

 // Give the message a subject
 ->setSubject('Your subject')

 // Set the From address with an associative array
 ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))

 // Set the To addresses with an associative array
 ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))

 // Give it a body
 ->setBody('Here is the message itself')

 // And optionally an alternative body
->addPart('<q>Here is the message itself</q>', 'text/html')

// Optionally add any attachments
->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('my-document.pdf'));
```

Answer (score 0):

this is using php and ajax it will work 100%

```
 <?php
        include "db.php";
        if(isset($_POST['tourid']))
       {

        $to=$_POST['email'];
        $file_name = "test/sample.pdf";                               
        require 'class/class.phpmailer.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->IsSMTP();                                           //Sets Mailer to send message using SMTP
        $mail->Host = '';                                           //Sets the SMTP hosts of your Email hosting, this for Godaddy
        $mail->Port = '';                                       //Sets the default SMTP server port
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                     //Sets SMTP authentication. Utilizes the Username and Password variables
        $mail->Username = '';                                        //Sets SMTP username
        $mail->Password = '';                                       //Sets SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = '';                                      //Sets connection prefix. Options are "", "ssl" or "tls"
        $mail->From = '';                                              //Sets the From email address for the message
        $mail->FromName = '';                                          //Sets the From name of the message
        $mail->AddAddress($to, 'Name');                                 //Adds a "To" address
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;                         ``                  //Sets word wrapping on the body of the message to a given number of characters
        $mail->IsHTML(true);                                            //Sets message type to HTML 
        $mail->AddAttachment($file_name);                                //Adds an attachment from a path on the filesystem
        $mail->Subject = 'Customer Details';                             //Sets the Subject of the message
        $mail->Body = 'Please Find Tour details in attached PDF File.';  //An HTML or plain text message body
        if($mail->Send())                                                //Send an Email. Return true on success or false on error
        {
           $message = '<label class="text-success">Tour Details has been send successfully...</label>';
           echo $message;
           unlink($file_name);
        }

        }
         else
        {

             echo "sending error";
        }



        ?>
```